# Designing a "Landscape application" for a Pocket PC

Tags: visual-studio, pocketpc

I would like to create an app for a pocket pc.

One of the features is that the user should rotate the pocket pc 90 degrees counterclockwise to opearate normally the app

How can someone design a "counterclockwise rotated" application with Visual studio?
Is there any option in VS that i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project, add a reference to Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.  Next, add a form and make it 320 (w) x 240 (h).  Add "using Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms;" to the top of your Program.cs file.  In your Main() method (before the form is loaded) add this line:

```
SystemSettings.ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Angle90;
```

(it may be Angle270 you want - I don't remember offhand).  When your app closes, you'll probably want to set the orientation back to Portrait.

Comment: But then again, I think you need to redesign all your screens if you want to support both orientations.