# Visual Basic Studio 2008 PocketPC: How to rotate screen ? (Landscape orientation)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, screen-orientation, smart-device, pocket

I am trying to make a small app for HP IPaq 1940 Pocket PC running Windows Mobile 2003, nothing fancy, only a few buttons, and some textboxes. The thing is - I cannot set the app screen orientation to landscape in Visual Basic Studio 2008. I found how can I make it fullscreen, how to resize it, but no matter how I try, I cannot make the form rotated to 270 degrees (Right handed PDA handling).

Unfortunately since its a dated environment, many links are rotten and many solutions which I have been searching are no longer available.

What I want:
[image: What I want]

This is what I tried: In documentation archive for VS 2008 I found that you should go to Tools>Options>Device Tools>Form Factors, select device for emulation and click Properties and enable rotation compatibility, which I have checked, and then Right click the form and select "Rotate Left/Right". But it is no use. When I launch the debugger this is how it shows:

What I get:

[image]

I can run the program on the physical device as well and it still shows in portrait position.

There are some solutions posted, but they seem quite advanced, and Im either too dumb to understand how to implement it correctly, or it is not working. This one didnt work for me because I think it is for C++ and I am doing Visual Basic: [Designing a "Landscape application" for a Pocket PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114905/designing-a-landscape-application-for-a-pocket-pc)

I tried all above for PocketPC 2003 and for Windows Mobile 2005.

I understand that this hardware soon is about to be of age to vote, but it has to be that way, no way around it.
Thank you for your time and effort.

This is a solution for C++ and C# which I managed to add a reference, but I get error "The tags are not valid outside of methods" (Sorry my Visual Basic Studio 2008 is not in English)
https://www.desigeek.com/blog/amit/2006/08/21/how-to-change-the-screen-orientation-on-a-phone-pocket-pc/

This one fell to link rot:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4fe24c00-e3fb-4f9d-856d-f77974274ef0/how-to-change-the-screen-orientation-programmatically-with-vbnet?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

Comment: Use web.archive.org for missing web sites: see here http://web.archive.org/web/20100218125127/http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2005/02/01/364834.aspx. This is the right way to do it. As it is C#, you may create a own cs file for this and use it from VB Net code. Or you create a separate  module for it.

Comment: Another good source for how to use pinvoke for functions not implemented in .NET is http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=ChangeDisplaySettingsEx&namespace=[All]

Comment: Accroding to a book about Compact Framework 2, there is a function      // Read the orientation.
     label1.Text = "Orientation is " + SystemSettings.ScreenOrientation.ToString();
     //  Set the orientation.
     SystemSettings.ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Angle90;